# Javascript checking if window is undefined

Tags: javascript, browser

I was writing a check to see if my code is running on the browser and I first tried the following 2 approaches:

```
if (window) {
    // do browser stuff
}


if (window !== undefined) {
    // do browser stuff
}
```

When I try using this code, I get an error saying `window` is not defined. However, when I try the following approach it works:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // do browser stuff
}
```

Why do the first 2 if statements throw an error but the third doesn't?

Comment: `typeof` is a special operator, its operand is allowed to be an undefined variable and no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the identity checks `window !== undefined` and `window` throw an error because window was not defined. That's exactly what the error is telling you when you try it in the console:

> VM49:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: iDoNotExist is not defined

I think the misconception that this should work comes from how the identity check is usually used. In functions we often perform this kind of check on the input parameter.

```
const myFunction = (inputParam) => {
   if (inputParam){
      console.log(inputParam)
   } else {
      console.log("invalid parameter")
   }
}

myFunction("hello")
// 'hello'

myFunction()
// 'undefined'

myFunction(null)
// 'undefined'

myFunction(undefined)
// 'undefined'
```

The `typeof`-operator on the other hand returns the type of its operand as a string. Since undefined is one of JavaScripts types the expression does not throw an error and returns 'undefined' instead.